# GlobalAllocPtr() always return same address for different Process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an application which can be launched multiple times simultaneously on Windows.

In this application, at the beginning, we call GlobalAllocPtr() to allocate a memory as below:

```
// allocate a structure
LPSlcDataMgr lpMgr = (LPSlcDataMgr)GlobalAllocPtr(GHND, sizeof(TSlcDataMgr));
```

We tested on two machines (both are XP professional 2002, one is SP2 , the other is SP3)
but on SP3, our applications will crash randomly

After investigation, we found:

1. on SP3 , `GlobalAllocPtr()` always return the same address for different application processes
2. but on SP2, it is ok, return different address for each process

Is it possible the `GlobalAllocPtr()` returning the same address on WinXP SP3 be the direct or indirect cause of our crash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization Possibly related?

Answer (score 6):

For the last 15 years or more, every sane OS has used virtual memory. Every process gets a full virtual address space *to itself*. So two different processes can have pointers to the same address without any problems or conflict. They never see each others' data, because they each have their own "copy" of that address, and every other address.

That's just how the OS works, and unless you're writing a kernel-mode driver, you don't need to know what the underlying physical addresses are, and you generally *don't know* what the underlying physical addresses are.

And no, this does not lead to crashes. Your problem is something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now VAS is clear for me, I agree with you, should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Memory management has moved on from Windows 3.1:

> Windows memory management does not
>   provide a separate local heap and
>   global heap. Therefore, the
>   GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc functions
>   are essentially the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366574(VS.85).aspx

Read the sections about file mapping for creating shared memory between processes,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply
But in my case, we don't want to share memory between processes
We just need each process's own memory address.

Comment: @michael.yue : Each process does get its own memory space; the address you're given is not a physical address, it's a virtual address.

Comment: @michael so just use `new`, `malloc`, or `Alloc` from the Concurrency Runtime.

Comment: @ildjam, from MSDN, it says:
--->If the function succeeds, the return value is a pointer to the first byte of the memory block<---
which is virtual address ?
if it is virtual address, why on SP3 always return same one, but on SP2 return different each time

Comment: @Steve-o,  we can't change like this, otherwise there will be a big impact on current application

Comment: @michael.yue : You really need to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) **before** going any further. Also, MSDN doesn't document `GlobalAllocPtr` any more; whatever documentation you're reading that mentions that function, it is likely uselessly old.

Comment: @ildjam : thanks, I read your recommend doc, But I am still confused, my understanding is even if it is a virtual address, different process should return different virtual address, because there is only one virtual address space in OS

Comment: @michael.yue : No, in a process there is only virtual address space, and in the OS there is physical address space and a table of process -> virtual address space mappings. It is **likely/expected/not unusual** that two different processes will be given the same virtual address for in-process allocations.

Comment: @ildjarn : hi, one question, do you know how to get physical address by VAS pointer, actually I want to print out physical address to see if they are same, but always print out 0x0 by *lpMgr, thanks in advance

Comment: @michael.yue : That's not possible in user-mode code. You'd need to write a device driver in order to see that.